# SCRIPT1030: Conditional compilation is turned off

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, conditional-compilation

I'm referencing this script in the header:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery.ui.all.css

And when I run my application, I get this error:

> SCRIPT1030: Conditional compilation is turned off

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y5529x3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) I should be doing something with `/*@cc_on @*/`. I have tried that but it doesn't recognize it in the `_Layout.cshtml` page.

Removing this line works:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery.ui.all.css"></script>
```

But I need the css files. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the use of the wrong tag. I used `<script>` in stead of `<link>`, because it's a `CSS` file.

It's an easy made mistake, so I'll leave it for those who gets this error too. Got me busy with it for like an hour or 2.